# Como funciona o segredo de Bittorrent Sync?

Tags: git, algoritmo, sparkleshare, sincronização

Estou procurando um alternativo completamente Código Aberto para o Bittorrent Sync, e parece que temos quase todos elementos lá: o Sparkleshare faria o que queria fazer, só faltando a conexão direta para computador não importa onde usando um segredo. Como esse segredo de Bittorrent Sync funciona, ou como implementaria um sistema assim?

[Edit: Eu sei usar git, com ou sem sparkleshare. A situação é que o git precisa saber com qual computador/servidor ligar, por isso precisa dum servidor. O Bittorrent Sync não usa servidor, basta que um computador que roda o programa esteja online. O Bittorrent Sync sabendo o segredo procura todos outros com o mesmo segredo e sincroniza eles. Estou procurando como fazer essa identificação de ponto de acesso na rede, assim que eu possa usar o Sparkleshare sem ter servidor fixo.]

(Eu aplicaria isso seja como protocolo novo no Git, seja como redireção para o SSH, esse último com a vantagem que poderá entrar em servidor etc sem que precise estar alcançável diretamente, usando o segredo).

(Crosspost para o SO em Inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594302/how-does-the-bittorrent-sync-secret-work)

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta não está relacionado diretamente com programação, ela seria mais adequada, por exemplo, ao [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Por não termos um equivalente em português seremos um pouco mais permissivos em relação a isso?

Comment: Na verdade quero saber como funciona para poder implementar (é questão de algoritmo).

Comment: Em que linguagem/ambiente/protocolo? O que já tentou?

Comment: Ambiente Linux no caso. Até posso fazer em Bash, mas sem saber como funciona não posso tentar em nenhum meio. Meu fim é poder ampliar o Git para poder fazer esse tipo de sincronização sem servidor nem conhecimento de localização de servidor pelo usuário de Git.

Comment: No SO em Inglês... até agora nada também... resolvi postar em adição também no Quora, vamos ver se algo de bom venha de lá...

Comment: @LaPingvino no cross-post tem uma resposta que explica a teoria de como funciona. É o que você queria? Você quer código? Se for o que você queria, posso colocar aqui uma tradução?

Comment: Pode, é sim o que queria saber :).

Answer (score 6):

Esta é uma tradução da [resposta do Jakob no SO em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594302/how-does-the-bittorrent-sync-secret-work/20723287#20723287), do post citado na pergunta:

> Como [foi dito pelo
>   BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/intl/de/sync/technology) (veja
>   também [o guia para
>   usuários](http://btsync.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/BitTorrentSyncUserGuide.pdf)),
>   o segredo é uma chave gerada randomicamente de 20 bytes ou mais.
>   Simplesmente as leis da probabilidade fazem virtualmente impossível
>   adivinhar. Há quatro tipos de segredos:
>
> - (mestre) segredos para acesso de leitura e gravação
> - segredos apenas para leitura
> - segredos para serem usados apenas uma vez (podem ser tanto de acesso completo como somente leitura)
> - segredos com suporte para encriptação (codificação) entre pares para acesso somente leitura encriptado
>
> Até onde eu entendi (e está registrado nessa
>   [discussão](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/21338-inofficial-protocol-specification/)
>   em que alguém tentou fazer engenharia reversa no protocolo do
>   BitTorrent Sync em Julho de 2013) os últimos três tipos de segredos
>   podem ser derivados do segredo mestre. Em particular isto inclui a
>   chave para a encriptação de arquivos para a transmissão entre pares.
>   Por isso a descoberta de pares usa hashes, de forma que o hash possa
>   ser usado para encontrar pares com o mesmo segredo sem precisar tornar
>   público o segredo.
>
> Antes de fazer engenharia reversa no BitTorrent Sync, lembre-se de que
>   o software é de fonte fechado e inclui rotinas para atualizarem
>   automaticamente à partir do site bittorrent.com. Isso implica no fato
>   de que a empresa pode mudar os detalhes da implementação (e instalar
>   backdoors arbitrários também). Ninguém pode garantir que não há um
>   método escondido que envia seus segredos mestre para a NSA, a não ser
>   que o código fonte seja analisado.